# Model prediction is only one class from all the classes in captcha recognition

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to make a model to predict **captcha letters and numbers.** but when I try to predict I found that all predictions result in only one class from all the `labels=33` classes. the first try from me was using learning rate of `keras.optimizer.adam(lr=0.001)` the all predictions is `1`
then I tried to change learning rate to 0.01 then all the results was S like in the image.

[image]

Some times it gives like this

[image]

I really don't know what is the cause of that. I have checked the data. thought of my splitting is only one class, but this is not found in my case
this is how I split the data:

```
(X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test) = train_test_split(data, label, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
lb = LabelBinarizer().fit(Y_train)
Y_train = lb.transform(Y_train)
Y_test = lb.transform(Y_test)
```

This is my data classes amounts to check unbalancing:

```
(array(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
        'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
        'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], dtype='<U1'),
 array([8286, 6393, 6332, 6316, 6427, 6173, 6699, 6404, 6956, 6272, 6331,
        6353, 6328, 6607, 6250, 6396, 6466, 5985, 6421, 6314, 6196, 6502,
        6542, 6417, 6435, 6421, 6396, 6341, 6107, 6131, 6360, 6383, 6457]))
```

and then I applied this model:

```
model=Sequential()
# First convolutional layer with max pooling
model.add(Conv2D(100, (5, 5), padding="same", input_shape=(40, 40, 1), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# Second convolutional layer with max pooling
model.add(Conv2D(200, (5, 5), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
# Second convolutional layer with max pooling
model.add(Conv2D(200, (5, 5), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
# Hidden layer with 500 nodes
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(500, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(33, activation="softmax"))

# Ask Keras to build the TensorFlow model behind the scenes
optimizer = keras.optimizers.adam(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), batch_size=128, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

I am thinking of :

> splitting problem? batch ? code bug?
>   I am running the model depending on this example model here:

[link of the code model](https://github.com/BenjaminWegener/CaptchaSolver/blob/master/CaptchaSolver.ipynb)

I am blocked in this part about 1 week and didn't find a solution

Answer (score 1):

When I see your case and your code, I think of two issues :

1. First of all, did you ballance your data first, in order to have the same amount of samples for each class, in the training set ? Unballanced data may provide bad results. How many samples per class do you have in the training set ?
2. Why don't you parse labelling on the entire label column first? It is true, you use the same labelizer for both Y_train and Y_test, but what if you have missing classes in the test set ? (this issue is related to the one above).

It is safer to do the following, and especially after data ballancing :

```
lb = LabelBinarizer()
lb_label = lb.fit_transform(label)
(X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test) = train_test_split(data, lb_label, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

3. I see in your examples that you have ambiguity between `B` and `6` and `S` and other characters. It seems that the model is underfit.
4. Your classes are not scalars but vectors, therefore the size of you output layer should be 2 dimensional, maybe (1, 33).
5. The size of your Conv2D must be smaller and smaller in a CNN architecture, but you have `100`, `200`, `200`, `500`, revising this might help improving your score, too.

Hoping this might help.

UPDATE

You may use also [THESE ARCHITECTURES](https://keras.io/applications/) in Keras.

Comment: I have added the amount of classes above and edited the question.

Comment: You have classes which are not scalars but vectors. Therefore, the size of the last layer should be 2D and not 33 as a scalar. Perhaps (1, 33)

Comment: I will try this also thanks, also I have added the link of the model I am trying to use above to check that model. it is the same I am using instead of number of classes I think and layers

Comment: You may also try the image classification architectures already available in Keras. I updated the answer and added the link. I tried `Inception` and got good results. You will not have to bother with those issues if you use them, they are already done.

Comment: Appreciate your points @Catalina , insufficient data is also a major cause at here, better try of augmenting data as well

Comment: @Nagakiran are you sure that the point is un sufficient data? can you see the example I am wroking on? I am using about 200k picture overall and he use 10k without the same error I am facing.

Comment: thats pretty good amount data, network architecture should also good enough to catch it, i have faced mainly data insufficient problems, when worked on it https://github.com/Nagakiran1/4-simple-steps-in-Builiding-OCR  @AmrMahmoud

Comment: Thanks. The problem as I mentioned above is that it is always predict one class or 2 rarely but not even random prediction. the question is what is the problem in my model?

Comment: I updated once again my answer. I did not run your code myself and I do not have access to the data you used, so my statements are only guesses. By the way, your data seems to be rather balanced.

Comment: coudn't solved! I have posted it in details with full code can you check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819482/cnn-model-predict-one-class-and-accuracy-is-99?noredirect=1#comment107607778_60819482

Comment: Once again: why don't you try an already implemented architecture in Keras or other library? People work on these architectures for years in order to find one which works correctly.